# How to import a module from another package in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Currently i'm having a file structure like below.

```
├── src
│   ├── common
│   │    ├──constants.py
│   │    └──configs.py
│   ├── utils
│   │    ├──module1.py
│   │    └──module2.py
│   └── service
│   │     ├──module3.py
│   │     └──module24.py
│   └── main.py
├── test
│   ├── utils
│   │    ├──test_module1.py
│   │    └──test_module2.py
```

My test_module1.py includes

```
# test_module1.py
import sys
sys.path.append("./.")

from src.utils.module1 import filter_file
from unittest import TestCase, main, mock
```

utils/module1.py includes

```
# module1.py
from common.constants import LOG_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT
...
```

Here, when i try to run test_module1.py file from root i get an error saying that,

```
$- python3 test/utils/test_module1.py
$- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common.constants'
```

what is the issue here

Comment: Try `sys.path.append(".." + os.sep + "..")` after also importing os to go up two folders.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it, works like this on Windows:

```
├── src
│   └── utils
│        └──lib.py
├── test
│   └── utils
│        └──bla.py
```

lib.py:

```
def test():
    print("woo")
```

bla.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(".." + os.sep + "..")

from src.utils.lib import test

test()
```

Comment: getting the same error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'. Btw did u run it from root by running python3 test/utils/test_module1.py ?

Comment: i'm using a linux machine

Comment: No, i ran it from within test/utils. If you want to execute it from within root, add the following: `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`. You can get rid of the other path append then if you always execute it from within root.

Comment: i did this also. it throws now "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common' " . It's because module1.py is calling constant from common package

Comment: You will then also have to add `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` inside your module1.py and import your common packages like you are inside root, so: `from src.common.constants import common_function`. If you do not want to alter your code inside of src, i think you have to add all sub-folders to path (`sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + os.sep + "src" + os.sep + "common")` etc.).